# Why does \\ not seem to work in Jest snapshots?

Tags: jestjs

EDIT 2: I've now tested the files in a React app. JavaScript works as expected so the only actual problem seems to be that Jest snapshots inconsistently handle escape characters including in way which aren't valid JS, which could make debugging confusing. Tests still work as they should, only looking at the snapshot could be confusing.

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate of the question regarding when to use single or double quotes. I am wondering why escaping a backslash doesn't seem to work in either JSX or Jest snapshots, yet escaping a quote does.

```
\\ should become \ yet it appears as \\ in the official Jest example
```

[https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/snapshot/**tests**/**snapshots**/link.react.test.js.snap](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/snapshot/__tests__/__snapshots__/link.react.test.js.snap)

I'm learning Jest and looking over their example for snapshot testing. On the test entitled it properly escapes quotes, the quotes are escaped correctly, but there are parts where two backslashes are together and they're both rendered in the snapshot.

Is this some unique thing or bug related to Jest snapshots?

Here's the test

```
it('properly escapes quotes', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(
      <Link>
        {"\"Facebook\" \\'is \\ 'awesome'"}
      </Link>
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

And Here's the snapshot output:

```
exports[`properly escapes quotes 1`] = `
<a
  className="normal"
  href="#"
  onMouseEnter={[Function]}
  onMouseLeave={[Function]}
>
  "Facebook" \\'is \\ 'awesome'
</a>
`;
```

Why aren't the double backslashes rendered as one backslash? After all isn't that how JavaScript works?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've now tested the files in a React app. JavaScript works as expected so the only actual problem seems to be that Jest snapshots inconsistently handle escape characters including in way which aren't valid JS, which could make debugging confusing.

Tests still work as they should, only looking at the snapshot could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and when I used double the number of slashes in the snapshot it worked.

e.g. instead of `\\`, use `\\\\`.

Maybe when the snapshot is read in, it goes through two levels of reduction in Jest.